# Can I install an uncertified eSIM profile provisioned by myself on Android?

Tags: sim-card, dual-sim, cellular-radio, esim

I would like to set up an SM-DP+ server to provision my own eSIM profiles. These usually get certified by GSMA and are used for large-scale Remote SIM Provisioning, but I would want to use this for home testing only, so getting official certification would be overkill.

I understand that I will need my own mobile network to work with it, which I also want to set up at home. My main concern is that either Android or the device manufacturers impose limitations that would only allow certified eSIM profiles to be installed on a device. I was thinking of using a Google Pixel 3A for testing, so I would be installing the eSIM profiles on this phone.

I also tried to find information on what's inside a SIM profile but there isn't much on the internet. I know it contains ISMI and some shared keys which it uses to connect to the MNOs network.

I would like to know what else is needed to create a functional eSIM profile and set up a server that provisions these to a Google Pixel 3A for a mock cellular network.

Comment: In the early 2000s, [Chaos Computer Club](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaos_Computer_Club) described how to clone a SIM card (exploiting flaws in the reference implementation for the authentication algorithm, which carriers discontinued soon after, hence SIM cards issued from ca. 2002 on are not vulnerable). According to them, connecting to a GSM network requires the IMSI (subscriber ID) and the Ki (key). That presumably also goes for UMTS networks, but LTE may be different. (Basis for my suspicion: my oldest SIM in my collection, issued in 2000, works with 2G and 3G, but not with 4G.)

Answer (score 2):

In order for your handset to establish secure communications with the SM-DP+ and then download and install a eSIM profile, the SM-DP+ will require 3 certificates signed by the GSMA's certificate issuer (DigiCert): DPtls (for initial contact), DPauth (for mutual authentication), and DPpb (for eSIM profile package binding).  Without these, the handset (actually the LPAd application and the eUICC) will refused to trust the SM-DP+.

The cost for the set of certificates is around $15k per year, and they can only be issued after a successful audit by the GSMA (which costs around a $20k).